# bootstrap card height-full card-header

Tags: html, flask, bootstrap-4

[image]

How can I align cards in a group? If I install `height-full` in `card-header` the whole layout breaks down

```
    <div class="pb-5 row justify-content-center">
        {% for movie in movie_list %}
            <div class="col-md-4 top-bottom">
                <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                    <div class="card-header text-center align-items-center d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">{{ movie.title }}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <img class="mx-auto d-block center" src={{ movie.image }} width="150">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                            <li>Рейтинг: {{ movie.vote_average }}</li>
                            <li>Дата выхода: {{ movie.release_date }}</li>
                        </ul>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block"
                                onclick="location.href='/movie/{{ movie.id }}'">Выбрать фильм
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

How I want to get
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the class `.h-100` to `.card` will do the trick.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ken717w/pen/zYvVvxM)

Comment: I wrote that if you add height-full then everything moves out

Comment: @sonfire You said you'd added it to `.card-header` didn't you? Can you provide a screenshot of how the layout breaks in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't set card height. If you want they seen same height you must set card height

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution

```
.card-header{
    min-height: 15vh!important;
    height: 100%!important;
}
```